# Can I plot multiple function curves in a single plot using ggplot() in a user-defined function?

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2, plot, user-defined-functions

I am trying to build a user-defined function which basically returns a ggplot of multiple function curves in a single plot. The plot will be a complex version of the plot below:

```
library(ggplot2)
 p <- ggplot() + xlim(0,4) + xlab("x")
 p <- p + geom_function(fun = function(x) 1*x)
 p <- p + geom_function(fun = function(x) 2*x)
 p <- p + geom_function(fun = function(x) 3*x)
 p <- p + geom_function(fun = function(x) 4*x)
 p
```

Unfortunately, I am not being able to plot it using a user defined function as below. It only returns me the last plot:

```
plot_func <- function(i) {
   p <- ggplot() + xlim(0,i) + xlab("x")
   for (i in 1:i) {
     p <- p + geom_function(fun = function(x) i*x)
   }
   print(p)
 }
plot_func(4)
```

Can anyone please tell me how to plot this using a user-defined function?
Thank you very much!!

Comment: Cross-posted on RStudio Community: https://community.rstudio.com/t/plotting-multiple-function-curves-in-a-single-plot-using-ggplot-in-a-user-defined-function/92061

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Add an `i` argument to the function and specify it in `args=` like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
plot_func1 <- function(i) {
   p <- ggplot() + xlim(0,i) + xlab("x")
   for (i in 1:i) {
     p <- p + 
        geom_function(fun = function(x, i) i*x, args = list(i = i))
   }
   print(p)
 }
plot_func1(4)
```

**2)** or use `bquote`:

```
library(ggplot2)
plot_func2 <- function(i) {
   p <- ggplot() + xlim(0,i) + xlab("x")
   for (i in 1:i) {
     p <- p + geom_function(fun = bquote(function(x) .(i)*x))
   }
   print(p)
 }
plot_func2(4)
```

**3)** or substitute i into the function like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
plot_func3 <- function(i) {
   p <- ggplot() + xlim(0,i) + xlab("x")
   for (i in 1:i) {
     p <- p + geom_function(fun = substitute(function(x) i*x, list(i = i)))
   }
   print(p)
 }
plot_func3(4)
```

**4)** or define the function as a character string with i substituted in and then parse it and convert it to a call object using [[1]]:

```
library(ggplot2)
plot_func4 <- function(i) {
   p <- ggplot() + xlim(0,i) + xlab("x")
   for (i in 1:i) {
     p <- p + 
        geom_function(fun = parse(text = sprintf("function(x) %d*x", i))[[1]])
   }
   print(p)
 }
plot_func4(4)
```

Comment: AWESOME!! Thank you very much for your solutions!! They all work perfectly. I didn't get any solution like this before from any book or post.

Comment: I've a doubt regarding why 1st option work. Is it the case if supplied via `args`, it'll force evaluation? I was trying to do the same thing when OP cross-posted on RStudio Community, and I had to use `local` to solve the issue. Otherwise, it was always taking latest updated value of the counter.

Comment: It works for me.  Just copy the code and paste it into R and when I do that it gives 4 lines.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. Yours work fine for me. I am asking why OP's method failed. If I specify with `args`, what's the speciality? Does it force evaluation at that point? Or, something else?

Comment: In that case it would make more sense to post your comment under the question.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the functional form of running ggplots by calling its `+` (via undocumented `+.gg()` method)  inside `Reduce` on list of aesthetic layers:

```r
plot_func <- function(i) {
  layers <- list(ggplot(), 
                 xlim(0, i),  
                 xlab("x"),
                 lapply(1:i, function(i) geom_function(fun = function(x) i*x)))
  
  p <- Reduce(ggplot2:::`+.gg`, layers)
  print(p)
}

plot_func(4)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! Your solution works as well, and is pretty unique!!